# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: python, cx-oracle

So I am getting this error below from cx_oracle.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\excel.py", line 493, in generate_excel_file
    df = get_datframe_from_sql_with_binds(sql_lu_status, cursor_analytics, {"v0": current_snapshot_id})
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\dataframes.py", line 52, in get_datframe_from_sql_with_binds
    rs, col_names = get_data_with_binds(sql,cursor, bind_vars)
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\data.py", line 129, in get_data_with_binds
    rs = cursor.fetchall()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
Error occured creating Excel file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\excel.py", line 493, in generate_excel_file
    df = get_datframe_from_sql_with_binds(sql_lu_status, cursor_analytics, {"v0": current_snapshot_id})
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\dataframes.py", line 52, in get_datframe_from_sql_with_binds
    rs, col_names = get_data_with_binds(sql,cursor, bind_vars)
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\data.py", line 129, in get_data_with_binds
    rs = cursor.fetchall()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

My query is as below:

```
 SELECT
    
                a.snapshot_date,
                a.change_type,
    
                a.lu_number,
                a.lu_title,
                a.date_type,
                a.date_before,
                a.date_after,
                a.value_before,
                a.value_after,
                a.lu_status_remarks as status_remarks,
                a.lu_category,            
                a.scrn_no,
                a.lu_description,
                a.lu_remarks,     
                
                
                listagg(b.preferred_trade_name, ';;;') within group (order by b.preferred_trade_name) as products,
                listagg(c.country_display_label,';;;') within group (order by c.country_display_label) as countries,
                listagg(d.registration_uid,';;;') within group (order by d.registration_uid) as registrations,
                listagg(g.application_stage,';;;') within group (order by g.application_stage) as application_stage,
                listagg(h.application_type,';;;') within group (order by h.application_type) as application_type,
                listagg(e.internal_ref_no,';;;') within group (order by e.internal_ref_no) as study_code,
                listagg(f.registration_name_details,';;;') within group (order by f.registration_name_details) as registration_name_details
                
    
    
            FROM
                python_event_stream a, 
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_PRODUCTS   b,
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_COUNTRIES  c,
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_REG        d,
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_STUDY_CODE e,
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_REG_NAME_DET   f,
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_REG_NAME_APP_STAGE g,
                V_PYTHON_LU_DISTINCT_REG_NAME_APP_TYPE  h
                 where 
                 a.snapshot_id_new = b.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = b.variation_request_id
                 and
                 a.snapshot_id_new = c.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = c.variation_request_id
                 and
                 a.snapshot_id_new = d.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = d.variation_request_id
                 and
                 a.snapshot_id_new = e.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = e.variation_request_id
                 and
                 a.snapshot_id_new = f.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = f.variation_request_id
                 and
                 a.snapshot_id_new = g.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = g.variation_request_id
                 and
                 a.snapshot_id_new = h.snapshot_id_new and a.variation_request_id = h.variation_request_id
                 
                and a.snapshot_id_new = :v0 AND a.TABLE_NAME = 'FACT_LOCAL_UPDATE_STATUS'
                AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1            
    
                GROUP BY
    
    
                a.snapshot_date,
                a.change_type,
    
                a.date_type,
                a.date_before,
                a.date_after,
                a.value_before,
                a.value_after,
                a.lu_status_remarks,
                a.lu_category,   
                a.scrn_no,         
                a.lu_number,
                a.lu_title,
                a.lu_description,
                a.lu_remarks
               
                order by lu_number
```

The query runs fine in Oracle.  When I export it out to Excel, the longest result of the listagg output is 1021 characters.  So I am not sure what the problem is.

I am creating a pandas dataframe, by sending the SQL into a function and returning the dataframe.

I cant convert to a clob, because then openpyxl doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Actually that is an Oracle error neither Python nor Pandas. So I wonder about *The query runs fine in Oracle*. Using latest data? How did you determine 1,021 chars is the longest? Try `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE` directive in `listagg` and see which column truncates.

Comment: I printed out the SQL being generated in python, and ran it in SQL Developer, no issues at all when I passed in the same bind variable being used at execution.  I exported the data from SQL Developer to Excel and used the length formula to get the lengths of the listagged colum output.

Comment: Avoid IDEs like SQL Developer that may have certain defaults. Try running this query at command line using SQL*Plus.

Comment: Surely the IDE can’t overcome inherent Oracle limitations